# Remove Div on Woocommerce Checkout Page When Cart Value is Zero

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a lot of free products on a site I run that members have access to after they join. They have to go through checkout again to get them (they are vouchers which have to be uniquely generated for each user, hence the need to go through checkout again).

When a user adds one of these products to cart and goes to checkout, I want to display a super simple checkout page. I'm really just looking to add a banner image and then the "place order" butter center aligned just below the image.

I managed to remove the bulk of the checkout fields using the following code:

```
function sv_free_checkout_fields() {

global $woocommerce ; 

// Bail we're not at checkout, or if we're at checkout but payment is needed
if ( ! is_checkout() || ( is_checkout() && WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}

if ( WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription() ) {
    return;
}

// remove coupon forms since why would you want a coupon for a free cart??
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

// remove order review section
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );

// Remove the "Additional Info" order notes
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );
// Unset the fields we don't want in a free checkout
function unset_unwanted_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // add or remove billing fields you do not want
    // list of fields: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2
    $billing_keys = array(
      'billing_first_name',
      'billing_last_name',  
      'billing_company',
        'billing_phone',
      'billing_email',
        'billing_address_1',
        'billing_address_2',
        'billing_city',
        'billing_postcode',
        'billing_country',
        'billing_state',
    );
    // unset each of those unwanted fields
    foreach( $billing_keys as $key ) {
        unset( $fields['billing'][$key] );
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'unset_unwanted_checkout_fields' );

// A tiny CSS tweak for the account fields; this is optional
function print_custom_css() {
    echo '<style>.create-account { margin-top: 6em; }</style>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_custom_css' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'sv_free_checkout_fields' );
```

So as of right now, any time one of these free products are added to cart and the user goes to checkout, it removes everything except the "Place Order" button (which I want to keep), some styling around that button, The "Billing Details" title on the left, plus a rectangular border around that title, and another rectangular box right below it. I can't seem to figure out how to remove these last few things.

Here's the code that I need to remove that created the box around the button:

```
body.woocommerce-cart .cart-collaterals, form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout 
#order_review {
width: 40%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

And here's the div I need to remove on the left hand side:

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">

    <h3>Billing details</h3>



    <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
        </div>

    </div>
```

I only need them removed when the cart total is zero though. I would also like to center the place order button, and add a banner above it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the div outlined above with:

```
<?php
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
if ( $cart_total != 0 ) {
?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">
<h3>Billing details</h3>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

That way if the cart value is **NOT** equal to zero it **will** display.

I've not tested it, but the theory is there. You may need to add zero total items to your cart and echo `WC()->cart->get_cart_total();` to check the output. It may return 0.00 or $0.00. In which case you'll need to amend the code accordingly.

Comment: Better use directly `if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { /* … */ }`

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance - I'm a novice. Where would I put that string you outlined? What I have done so far of uploaded the first section of code outlined in my initial message in a snippet using the "Code Snippets" plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec The only problem with that is, as CCHert has outlined, the cart can have items in it, but still total zero. He wants to prevent display if the total is zero not if the cart is empty.

Comment: It looks like the code is contained within woocommerce/templates/checkout/ **form-billing.php**. However, if you make changes to this file directly it will be overwritten when you update the plugin. So I'd take a look at how to [override the plugin templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) via your theme.